# Ember Data: what event is triggered after a model reloads

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Using Ember Data, if a model is reloaded, what event is triggered?  Here's an example of a reload request:

```
myModel.reload()
```

I would have expected the didLoad event to trigger, but that's not the case.

Here's a jsbin that demonstrates this:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tufule/1/edit?html,js,console,output

You'll see in the jsbin that didLoad gets called when the model first loads, but reloading the model (by clicking the 'reload' link) doesn't trigger the didLoad event.

Here are all of the documented events, but there's nothing there for reload: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#event_didLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of keywords that make the difference:

- reload:

  > Reload the record **from the adapter**.
- didLoad:

  > Fired when the record is loaded **from the server**.

You probably want to observe/use a combination of the `isReloading` and `isLoaded` properties.

Comment: Thank you @givanse. isReloading is the one that works on reloading.  It gets set to true when attempting to reload and set to false once reloading is complete.